# SQL Where clause change causes unexpected results

Tags: sql-server

I am having a problem with the Where clause in a query.  Why does the first query give a different result than the second query?

The first query is:

```
select distinct
    [Event Code] = evt_code,
    [Event Category] = etc_code,
    [Acronym] = evt_acronym_ext,
    [Remit To Sort Name] = cst_sort_name_dn,
    [Rec #] = cst_recno,
    [Honorarium Amount] = case when fac_honorarium_amount_ext is null then 0.00 else fac_honorarium_amount_ext end,
    [Speaker type] = spt_code
from 
    ev_event (nolock)
inner join 
    ev_event_ext (nolock) on evt_key_ext = evt_key 
inner join 
    ev_event_category (nolock) on etc_key = evt_etc_key and etc_delete_flag = 0
inner join 
    ev_event_faculty (nolock) on fac_evt_key = evt_key and fac_delete_flag = 0
inner join 
    ev_event_faculty_ext (nolock) on fac_key_ext = fac_key --and fac_honorarium_amount_ext is not null and fac_honorarium_amount_ext > 0.0
inner join 
    co_customer (nolock) on cst_key = fac_cst_key and cst_delete_flag = 0
inner join 
    ev_event_speaker (nolock) on spk_fac_key = fac_key and spk_delete_flag = 0
inner join 
    ev_event_speaker_type (nolock) on spt_key = spk_spt_key and spt_delete_flag = 0
where 
    evt_code like '416%A' or evt_code like '516%A'
    and spt_code in ('Ed Fdn Speaker', 'Ed Fdn Author', 'Ed Fdn Conf Chair')
order by 
    evt_code
```

The second query is:

```
select distinct
    [Event Code] = evt_code,
    [Event Category] = etc_code,
    [Acronym] = evt_acronym_ext,
    [Remit To Sort Name] = cst_sort_name_dn,
    [Rec #] = cst_recno,
    [Honorarium Amount] = case when fac_honorarium_amount_ext is null then 0.00 else fac_honorarium_amount_ext end,
    [Speaker type] = spt_code
from 
    ev_event (nolock)
inner join 
    ev_event_ext (nolock) on evt_key_ext = evt_key 
inner join 
    ev_event_category (nolock) on etc_key = evt_etc_key and etc_delete_flag = 0
inner join 
    ev_event_faculty (nolock) on fac_evt_key = evt_key and fac_delete_flag = 0
inner join 
    ev_event_faculty_ext (nolock) on fac_key_ext = fac_key --and fac_honorarium_amount_ext is not null and fac_honorarium_amount_ext > 0.0
inner join 
    co_customer (nolock) on cst_key = fac_cst_key and cst_delete_flag = 0
inner join 
    ev_event_speaker (nolock) on spk_fac_key = fac_key and spk_delete_flag = 0
inner join 
    ev_event_speaker_type (nolock) on spt_key = spk_spt_key and spt_delete_flag = 0
where 
    (evt_code like '416%A' 
     and spt_code in ('Ed Fdn Speaker', 'Ed Fdn Author', 'Ed Fdn Conf Chair') )
    or 
    (evt_code like '516%A' 
     and spt_code in ('Ed Fdn Speaker', 'Ed Fdn Author', 'Ed Fdn Conf Chair') )
order by 
    evt_code
```

Comment: The first query will return all rows with evt_code LIKE '416%A' regardless of spt_code.  The second uses and `AND` operator so those rows must also have one of the specified spt_code values.

Comment: It's to do with the order of evaluation of your `WHERE` clause, particularly as the second query is using parentheses which affects evaluation order. So in your first query, you're finding the resultset has event code `416%A` but not filtered by speaker type?

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 1):

Your first query you are evaluating '416%A' by it self. You can wrap ONLY that in parentheses to avoid this...

```
where (evt_code like '416%A' or evt_code like '516%A') AND
spt_code in ('Ed Fdn Speaker', 'Ed Fdn Author', 'Ed Fdn Conf Chair')
```

Answer (score 0):

The database is interpreting the first where clause as follows:

```
evt_code like '416%A' 
and (spt_code in ('Ed Fdn Speaker', 'Ed Fdn Author', 'Ed Fdn Conf Chair') 
     or evt_code like '516%A')
    )
```

In plain English: if `evt_code` is like `'416%A'`, then the where clause is satisfied if either `spt_code` is in any of the 3 terms OR evt_code is like 516%A, or both.

It's not technically accurate to say that the database adds it's own parentheses, but that's a good way to picture it.